# System.NullReferenceException Object reference not set to an instance of an object. on Model instantiation - SOMETIMES

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm getting System.NullReferenceException
Object reference not set to an instance of an object on instantiation of a model but only sometimes. My users are experiencing the error sometimes, but once they resubmit the exception does not occur. I can't figure out why the error is happening.

Here is my error log from ELMAH:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.


at Plus.Controllers.Review.ReviewNoteController.Save(ReviewNoteViewModel viewModel) in C:\Users\Rhys\Documents\Development\witplus-master\Plus\Controllers\Review\ReviewNoteController.cs:line 139
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Here is my code:

```
// Update Note
                if (viewModel.ID != 0)
                {
                    ReviewNote rn = _repository.Get<ReviewNote>(viewModel.ID);
                    MapViewModelToModel(rn, viewModel);
                    _repository.Update<ReviewNote>(rn);
                }
                // Create Note
                else
                {
                    ReviewAnswer ra = _repository.Get<ReviewAnswer>(viewModel.AnswerId);
                    bool newAnswer = false;
                    // Check if practice or checklists
                    if (viewModel.Referrer == Referrer.ReviewPractice)
                    {
                        // Create a new answer if it hasn't been answered yet. Could have made a bool in the GET method, but it's best to recheck to make sure no-one has answered in the mean time.
                        if (hasNoAnswer_PracticeLevel(viewModel.QuestionId))
                        {
                            ra = new ReviewAnswer();
                            ra.entityLevelAudit = true;
                            ra.entityId = this.LoggedInEntity.EntityId;
                            ra.questionId = viewModel.QuestionId;
                            ra.lastUpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
                            _repository.Save<ReviewAnswer>(ra);
                            newAnswer = true;
                            viewModel.AnswerId = ra.Id;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Create a new answer if it hasn't been answered yet.
                        if (hasNoAnswer_Checklist(viewModel.QuestionId))
                        {
                            ra = new ReviewAnswer();
                            ra.entityLevelAudit = false;
                            ra.entityId = this.LoggedInEntity.EntityId;
                            ra.questionId = viewModel.QuestionId;
                            ra.userId = this.SelectedUser.UserId;
                            ra.lastUpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
                            _repository.Save<ReviewAnswer>(ra);
                            newAnswer = true;
                            viewModel.AnswerId = ra.Id;
                        }
                    }

                    ReviewNote rn = new ReviewNote();
                    rn.auditID = ra.Id;
                    rn.Type = (int)this.LoggedInUser.ReviewTypeId; //Audit Note type is the user audit type
                    MapViewModelToModel(rn, viewModel);
                    _repository.Save<ReviewNote>(rn);
                }
```

The error is occuring at line 139 which is:

```
ReviewNote rn = new ReviewNote(); // 6th last line.
```

The ReviewNote Model code is:

```
using Plus.Models.UserModel;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Plus.Models.Review
{
    public class ReviewNote : BaseModel
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Column("AuditNoteId")]
        public int ID { get; set; } // AuditNoteId

        public int auditID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("auditID")]
        public virtual ReviewAnswer Answer { get; set; }

        [StringLength(10000), AllowHtml, Column("noteText")]
        public string Text { get; set; } //noteText

        [StringLength(200), Column("noteFile")]
        public string URL { get; set; } //noteFile

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime), Column("lastUpdateDate")]
        public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }//lastUpdateDate

        [Column("showNoteToAll")]
        public bool VisibleToAll { get; set; } //ShowNoteToAll

        [Required]
        public int NoteBy { get; set; } //NoteBy
        [ForeignKey("NoteBy")]
        public virtual User By { get; set; }

        [Column("noteType")]
        public int Type { get; set; } //NoteType
    }
}
```

Here is the BaseModel code:

```
public abstract class BaseModel
    {
        [NotMapped, JsonIgnore]
        public Alias Alias { get; set; }

        [NotMapped, JsonIgnore]
        public IDictionary<string, object> AliasDictionary { get; set; }

        [NotMapped, JsonIgnore]
        public AppUserDTO LoggedInAppUser { get; set; }

        [NotMapped, JsonIgnore]
        public UserDTO LoggedInUser { get; set; }

        [NotMapped, JsonIgnore]
        public EntityDTO LoggedInEntity { get; set; }

        [NotMapped, JsonIgnore]
        public ResourceDTO LoggedInUsersResource { get; set; }

        [NotMapped, JsonIgnore]
        public virtual ICollection<MenuItemClaim> MenuSystemTreeClaims { get; set; }

        [NotMapped, JsonIgnore]
        public IStateProvider UserSession { get; set; }

        [NotMapped, JsonIgnore]
        public UserDTO SelectedUser { get; set; }

        [NotMapped, JsonIgnore]
        public TermsAndConditions TAC { get; set; }

        [NotMapped, JsonIgnore]
        public string PageClaimValue { get; set; }
    }
```

I can't see why there would be an NullReferenceException on the instantiation of ReviewNote at all.
If anyone could offer a suggestion it would be most helpful because it's becoming more and more of an issue for my users.

My project is ASP.NET MVC5 with Identity 2 and Entity Framework 6.2. I'm thinking the error only started after I upgraded Entity Framework 6.1 to 6.2, but it's just a guess.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens in `BaseModel`?

Comment: Just a model to store Globalish variables. I've updated the question to show it.

Comment: Are you sure the line 139 of the version that threw the exception is the same line as the one in your current source? Seems an unlikely location for that exception to be thrown, as nothing is initialized when the object is created. Have you tried adding some logging? My guess is that ```ra``` might be null...

Comment: Yes I have checked and it's absolutely the right source code. The stack output is from Elmah.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As commenters have noted, there doesn't seem to be anything in the construction of `ReviewNote` that should generate a `NullReferenceException`, and no code outside your own is showing up in the stacktrace.

I have had issues in the past where the line number given in a stacktrace was a few lines off from where the actual error occurred. If you can't catch it with a debugger attached, all I can suggest is that you add some kind of information to supplement the line number. An easy way to do this is an incrementing integer:

```
int debugId = 0;
try
{
    ReviewNote rn = new ReviewNote(); // debugId == 0
    ++debugId;
    rn.auditID = ra.Id; // debugId == 1
    ++debugId;
    rn.Type = (int)this.LoggedInUser.ReviewTypeId; // debugId == 2
    ++debugId;
    MapViewModelToModel(rn, viewModel); // debugId == 3
    ++debugId;
    _repository.Save<ReviewNote>(rn); // debugId == 4
}
catch (NullReferenceException nre)
{
    throw new Exception("debugId:" + debugId, nre);
}
```

The value of `debugId` will tell you which line the failure occurred on

Comment: thanks for this suggestion. It was actually line 140, which is a bit annoying that it doesn't show the correct line number.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know if that's a consequence of inlining in release builds or something else (I only ever saw it in release builds).

Comment: That's a really brilliant idea to add a counter that is incremented for each field.